# TYPO3 - putting of fileadmin in an standalone git repository?

Tags: git, architecture, typo3

I would like to separate TYPO3 site code (`typo3conf`) and site data (`fileadmin`).

It will make branching and merging more flexible.

What is the best practice to do it ?

I tried symlinks, but TYPO3 6.2 LTS asks not to use symlinks for `fileadmin` and gives warnings in Install tool.

Answer (score 0):

Actually you should gitignore whole `fileadmin`, `uploads`, `typo3temp` and `typo3` folders, as i.e. `fileadmin` is supposed to keep files uploaded by editors via backend.

You can put your templates i.e. under `typo3conf/templates` folder then (as imho it shouldn't be accessible via BE tools) (note that you can have some problems with TemplaVoila kickstarter at the beginning, but it's possible to make TV working anyway)

Comment: Great idea ! But what to do If I would like to track my `fileadmin` / `uploads` data also without to mix it with site development code ?

Comment: Then most probably git submodules will interest you ;) http://git-scm.com/book/en/v2/Git-Tools-Submodules

Comment: Think so too. `www/fileadmin` & `www/uploads`. The one problem, what in this configuration I should make 2 repositories. And I would like to have only one `data` repository with `fileadmin` & `uploads` folders inside.